# Is there something similar to system restore in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, restore

I would want to know if there is a command that can change my system back to the state at some point in time, including changing any files that may have been edited

Comment: I am not sure about some fixed point, but you take your system to point when it was newly installed, without any setting or configuration changed. Like when your system starts first time with default setting..

Comment: There is an archivation system, is that what do you need?

Comment: @Danatela i need to restore my system to 3 hours back. Meaning i want everything to be a sit was 3 hours ago. I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Comment: Sorry, you should make "restore point" in this time, like in Windows. Or construct the time machine and go then ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you created that restore point yourself so the answer will be: NO.

For future usage: use [Déjà Dup](http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/).

> Déjà Dup is a simple — yet powerful — backup tool included with Ubuntu. It offers the power of rsync with incremental backups, encryption, scheduling, and support for remote services.
>
> With Déjà Dup, you can quickly revert files to previous versions or restore missing files from a file manager window. It’s a graphical frontend to Duplicity, which itself uses rsync. It offers the power of rsync with a simple interface.

And always make a backup when altering files unless you can remember what you did ;)

Answer (score 2):

you should try timeshift (https://launchpad.net/timeshift)
It is similar to windows restore points. You can save the state of the system and restore it if you want